# What algorithm should I use for "genetic AI improvement"

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

First of all: This is *not* a question about how to make a program play Five in a Row. Been there, done that.

### Introductory explanation

I have made a five-in-a-row-game as a framework to experiment with genetically improving AI (ouch, that sounds awfully pretentious). As with most turn-based games the best move is decided  by assigning a score to every possible move, and then playing the move with the highest score. The function for assigning a score to a move (a square) goes something like this:

1. If the square already has a token, the score is 0 since it would be illegal to place a new token in the square.
2. Each square can be a part of up to 20 different winning rows (5 horizontal, 5 vertical, 10 diagonal). The score of the square is the sum of the score of each of these rows.
3. The score of a row depends on the number of friendly and enemy tokens already in the row. Examples:

   - A row with four friendly tokens should have infinite score, because if you place a token there you win the game.
   - The score for a row with four *enemy* tokens should be very high, since if you *don't* put a token there, the opponent will win on his next turn.
   - A row with both friendly and enemy tokens will score 0, since this row can never be part of a winning row.

Given this algorithm, I have declared a type called TBrain:

```
type
  TBrain = array[cFriendly..cEnemy , 0..4] of integer;
```

The values in the array indicates the score of a row with either N friendly tokens and 0 enemy tokens, or 0 friendly tokens and N enemy tokens. If there are 5 tokens in a row there's no score since the row is full.

It's actually quite easy to decide which values should be in the array. Brain[0,4] (four friendly tokens) should be "infinite", let's call that 1.000.000.  vBrain[1,4] should be very high, but not so high that the brain would prefer blocking several enemy wins rather than wining itself

Concider the following (improbable) board:

```
  0123456789
 +----------
0|1...1...12
1|.1..1..1.2
2|..1.1.1..2
3|...111...2
4|1111.1111.
5|...111....
6|..1.1.1...
7|.1..1..1..
8|1...1...1.
```

Player 2 should place his token in (9,4), winning the game, *not* in (4,4) even though he would then block 8 potential winning rows for player 1. Ergo, vBrain[1,4] should be (vBrain[0,4]/8)-1. Working like this we can find optimal values for the "brain", but again, this is *not* what I'm interested in. I want an *algorithm* to find the best values.

I have implemented this framework so that it's totally deterministic. There's no random values added to the scores, and if several squares have the same score the top-left will be chosen.

### Actual problem

That's it for the introduction, now to the interesting part (for me, at least)

I have two "brains", vBrain1 and vBrain2. How should I iteratively make these better? I Imagine something like this:

1. Initialize vBrain1 and vBrain2 with random values.
2. Simulate a game between them.
3. Assign the values from the winner to the loser, then randomly change one of them slightly.

This doesn't seem work. The brains don't get any smarter. Why?

Should the score-method add some small random values to the result, so that two games between the same two brains would be different? How much should the values change for each iteration? How should the "brains" be initialized? With constant values? With random values?

Also, does this have *anything* to do with AI or genetic algorithms at all?

PS: The question has nothing to do with Five in a Row. That's just something I chose because I can declare a very simple "Brain" to experiment on.

Comment: I've written a Four in a Row using a neural network. (It was really bad!) Are you interested in the code and the work I've done for school about it?

Comment: Depends. Is it really, really bad, or merely really bad? :-)   Seriously, I know _nothing_ about neural networks, and I feel that would be to complicated for me. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I'm not convinced your 'vBrain' is enough: Wouldn't it treat the row '111222' identically to '121212'? The two are very different strategically. Also, in your example board, there are many more than 8 sets of 5 enabled or blocked by playing in (4,4).

Comment: @Nick: You are correct that (4,4) would block even more than the 8 wins, but the point was that Brain[1,4] must be sufficiently lower than [0,4] so that the AI shouldn't prefer blocking two enemy wins over actually winning itself.

111222 is not equal to 121212. First off, there should be an empty cell. Consider the horizontal row "1.11x1.2.". The "X" position can be part of 5 winning rows: 1.11x, .11x1, 11x1., 1x1.2 and x1.2. ,each adding a score to the total.

Comment: Right, but Brain[1,4] must be way less than 1/8, since the score for (4,4) will be way more than 8. It's not clear to me how you calculate the score for a cell in a row with both friendly and enemy tokens, though.

Comment: @Nick: "how you calculate the score for a cell in a row with both friendly and enemy tokens" - You don't :-)   (See point 3 above)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thinking of the whole row, not just the 5 cells in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes you can make a *brain* smarter by using genetic algorithms techniques.

Randomness, or mutation, plays a significant part on genetic programming.

I like this tutorial, [Genetic Algorithms: Cool Name & Damn Simple](http://lethain.com/entry/2009/jan/02/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/).
(It uses Python for the examples  but it's not difficult to understand them)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to approach this problem like a genetic algorithm, you will need an entire population of "brains".  Then evaluate them against each other, either every combination or use a tournament style.  Then select the top X% of the population and use those as the parents of the next generation, where offspring are created via mutation (which you have) or genetic crossover (e.g., swap rows or columns between two "brains").

Also, if you do not see any evolutionary progress, you may need more than just win/loss, but come up with some kind of point system so that you can rank the entire population more effectively, which makes selection easier.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Neuro Evolution of Augmenting Tologies](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/neat.html) (NEAT). A fancy acronymn which basically means the evolution of neural nets - both their structure (topology) and connection weights. I wrote a .Net implementation called SharpNEAT that you may wish to look at. SharpNEAT V1 also has a Tic-Tac-Toe experiment.

http://sharpneat.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I was going to post this, but you seem to have beaten me to it. Ken Stanley's work here is great. See also: http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~kstanley/ and http://nerogame.org/